# Fire 7 ADB Device offline

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to connect via USB with my Fire 7 I just got.  It recognizes it, but says it is "offline."  I remember in the past, you want that warning to pop up on the device asking you if you want to trust this computer but that never shows up.  I have developer options enabled and usb debugging enabled.

Have tried "revoking permissions" and disabling/re-enabling USB debugging and restarting computer and device.  Also have tried 5 different USB ports.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing your adb in android studio and connect it again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all run `adb kill-server` and then run `adb devices`

If it doesn't work, try to upgrade `platform-tools`